# mysql: increment maximum field value on insert

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a field called 'sort' which contains sorting number. When I add a new row, I would like the sort field to be filled with the maximum existing value + 1. I tried this:

```
insert into highlights set sort=max(sort)+1
```

but I get a 1111 error "Invalid use of group function"

If I try with a subquery,

```
insert into highlights set sort=(select max(sort) from highlights)+1
```

I get a 1093 error since apparently I cannot subquery the same table I am inserting into.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this

```
 insert into highlights set sort=(select max(h1.sort)+1 from highlights h1);
```

Comment: thanks! it works! I'll put it as answered as soon as SO lets me do so :) thanks a lot!!!!